# Content loaded with ajax not triggering jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have the following draggable and selectable jQuery codes for item dragging/ selecting them all, the script works fine until the page is changed and the content inside `<div id="content"></div>` is loaded via ajax, then the draggable and selectable does not recognize the elements and does not work at all.

HTML of `<div id="content"></div>` before ajax page load:

```
<div id="content">
   <div class="files_">
     <div class="item_clickable"><span>hello element</span></div>
     <div class="item_clickable"><span>hello element</span></div>
     <div class="item_clickable"><span>hello element</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

HTML loaded from ajax call:

```
<div class="files_">
         <div class="item_clickable"><span>hello element</span></div>
         <div class="item_clickable"><span>hello element</span></div>
         <div class="item_clickable"><span>hello element</span></div>
 </div>
```

Draggable is applied on:

```
.files  <div class="files"></div>
```

example of page load code:

```
function (event, url, manual) {
    if (typeof manual === "undefined") {
        manual = false;
    }
    if (typeof url === "undefined") {
        link = $(this);
        if (link.data('no-ajax') === true)
            return;
        var href = link.attr("href"),
            target = (typeof link.data('target') !== "undefined") ? link.data('target') : '#content',
            append = (typeof link.data('append') !== "undefined") ? link.data('append') : false,
            changeUrl = (typeof link.data('change-url') === "undefined") ? true : link.data('change-url'),
            type = (typeof link.data('type') !== "undefined") ? link.data('type') : 'GET';
        if (!href || href === "#" || href === "javascript:void(0);" || href === "javascript:void(0)")
            return;
        console.log(changeUrl);
    } else {
        target = '#content';
        type = "GET";
        append = false;
        changeUrl = true;
        var href = url;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: href,
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function () {
            Buckty.loading('s');
        }
    }).always(function () {
        Buckty.loading('h');
    }).done(function (data) {
        var content = $(data).filter('#content').html();
        var matches = data.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/);
        if (matches) {
            var title = matches[1];
        }
        if (title)
            document.title = title;
        if (content) {
            if (append === false)
                $(target).html(content);
            else
                $(target).append(content);
        } else
            $(target).html(data);
        if (changeUrl) {
            manualStateChange = manual;
            History.pushState({}, document.title, href);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

draggable and selectable script:

```
if ($(".files_").length) {

    jQuery(".files_").selectable();



    // manually trigger the "select" of clicked elements
    jQuery(".files_ > div").click(function (e) {
        if (e.metaKey == false) {
            // if command key is pressed don't deselect existing elements
            $(".files_ > div").removeClass("ui-selected");
            $(this).addClass('ui-selected')
        } else {
            if ($(this).hasClass("ui-selected")) {
                // remove selected class from element if already selected
                $(this).removeClass("ui-selected");
            } else {
                // add selecting class if not
                $(this).addClass("ui-selecting");
            }
        }

        //$( ".files_" ).data("files_")._mouseStop(null);
    });

    // starting position of the divs
    jQuery(".folder_container ul li").droppable({
        accept: '.files_ .file_item',
        drop: function (event, ui) {

            console.log(ui);
        }
    });
    jQuery(".files_ .file_item").draggable({
        helper: drag_me,
        cancel: '.uploading',
        cursor: 'move',
        cursorAt: {
            left: 0,
            top: 0
        }
    });

}
```

The ajax call works on every click on any page or element, but the JavaScript for elements that are loaded from ajax call does not effect to JavaScript events.

if it was about some sort of small code i would have inserted it inside success function , but the code is large , there is not only draggable and selectable but there are to many other events , thats why i'm avoiding to insert it inside success function

it would be nice to have a good solution to set the bunch of code to make it work even after ajax page load.

Comment: You will have to create a callback function after your success function.

Comment: @JeroenBellemans if it was about some sort of small code i would have inserted it inside success function , but the code is large , there is not only draggable and selectable but there are to many other events , thats why i'm avoiding to insert it inside success function

Comment: Arsh, can you share the draggable event binding code? Looks like you will have to delegate the event to the parent div.

Comment: @azizpunjani updated my question with code of draggable event

Comment: If you create the jsFiddle for this, it will be useful for someone to answer.

Comment: @GaneshKumar problem is when i load content with ajax it does not trigger the events when one of the elements is elected or clicked , so i can't make jsfiddle of page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by wrapping all other code inside an function like this:

```
Buckty.load_script = function(){

 // whole code here 
}
```

and then did call it inside success function of ajax page load:

```
Buckty.load_script();
```